# Looking for 70s short story about dying man and a deer

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

The story was in a sci fi anthology I read in 75. Terminally ill man watching a deer in the tree line from his hospital room window. Not the story "Time Deer."

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Presumably there is a science fiction or fantasy element to the story?

Comment: It was in a sci-fi anthology. Was not a classic sci-fi type read, like Time Deer.

Comment: @RoyBaty - what do you mean by "_Was not a classic sci-fi type read_"? Are there any extra details you can [edit] in to your question? What was the man dying of? What was the deer doing? Was this set in the future? What made it science fiction?

Comment: It was not a tech-oriented story, no spaceships, aliens, future worlds. Man was in his hospital bed, his window had a view of a tree line from which the deer would appear and seem to acknowledge his presence. Don’t know what he was dying of. I don’t know what made it science fiction, but it was in a science fiction collection that I bought (required) as part of a science fiction class in 1974.